# Selection Sort does not return a sorted array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, max, comparable

I am trying to write a selection sort where I find the maximum in the (sub)array bounded by the int upper, and swap the current value with the max.

I have written three separate methods—I have a method for finding the index of the maximum value in the array, a method for swapping two values, and a sort method for actual sorting. I've tried debugging but am not very good at it...

```
public static void sort(Comparable[] array)
   {
      int maxindex = 0;
      for(int k=0; k<array.length; k++)
      {
         maxindex = findMax(array, array.length-k);
         if(maxindex < k)
            swap(array, k, maxindex); 
      }   
   }

public static int findMax(Comparable[] array, int upper)
   {  //"upper" controls where the inner loop of the selection sort ends
      Comparable max = array[0];
      int maxindex = 0;
      for(int i = 1; i<upper; i++)
      {
         if(max.compareTo(array[i])<0)
         {
            max = array[i];
            maxindex = i;
         }
      }
      return maxindex;
   }

public static void swap(Object[] array, int a, int b)
   {
      Object save = array[b];
      array[b] = array[a];
      array[a] = save; 
   }
```

I generate a random array and call the sort and print out the "sorted" array, except that the printed array is not sorted at all...

Comment: Please do not use raw-types. You are using `Comparable` without specifying its generic type. The only reason this is still valid Java is to support Java version 4 and earlier. There is no valid reason to use raw-types, except you are working with those versions. Also, your swap method should be made generic instead of accepting `Object[]` else you could polute your heap without the compiler being able to protect you..

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! I do have a very similar set of methods using double[] arrays, but my teacher wanted me to write both. And seeing how similar they are, I just thought to include my Comparable methods

Comment: Its just that it should be `public static <T> int findMax(Comparable<T>[] array`, ...)` notice the two `<T>`. And then also `public static <T> void swap(T[] array, ...)`. I.e. making them generic and using java generics instead of raw types :) That gives you more type safety and help by the compiler in order to avoid bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I took your code and made some modifications in `sort` as well as `findMax` function. Now, we are getting correct output.

1. `sort` function: I'm not sure why you have condition before the swap, it will prevent some of the `findMax` from swapping. Also, my guess is you are doing `array.length - k` because you might want to keep the maximum in the last index and loop through to find next maximum and so on. To do that your logic seems to be wrong.
2. `findMax` function: Index should start at `0` and go till `upper`.

See the below code for details:

```
public static void sort(int[] array) {
    int maxindex = 0;
    for(int k=array.length - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
        maxindex = findMax(array, k);
        swap(array, k, maxindex);
    }
}

public static int findMax(int[] array, int upper) {  
    //"upper" controls where the inner loop of the selection sort ends
    int max = array[0];
    int maxindex = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <= upper; i++) {
        if(max < array[i]) {
            max = array[i];
            maxindex = i;
        }
    }
    return maxindex;
}
```

Input: `[4, 2, 3, 8, 7, 1, 9, 10, 15, 12, 11, 13]`

Output: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15]`

Answer (score 0):

Since comparable is a raw type. References to generic type Comparable should be parameterised. Not recommended to use raw datatype, unless it is necessary.

The below program has few modifications done from your code. You can compare and it runs on O(n^2) complexity.

The main issue in your code is in **findMax()** function, the function is made static by hardcoding the value.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class XYZ {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        sort(new Integer[] { 1, 5, 2, 11, 4 });
    }

    public static void sort(Comparable[] array) {
        int maxindex = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < array.length; k++) { 
            maxindex = findMax(array, k);
            if (maxindex > k)
                swap(array, k, maxindex);
            //  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        }
    }

    public static int findMax(Comparable[] array, int startIndex) {
        Comparable max = array[startIndex];
        int maxindex = 0;
        for (int i = startIndex; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (max.compareTo(array[i]) < 0) {
                max = array[i];
                maxindex = i;
            }
        }
        return maxindex;
    }

    public static void swap(Object[] array, int a, int b) {
        Object save = array[b];
        array[b] = array[a];
        array[a] = save;
    }
}
```